# Draw a nice neat arc without the massive right angle and have nice corners instead

Tags: javascript, vector, path, automatic-ref-counting, raphael

I've made an arc in `Raphael` what I was aiming for was just one arc with out the 
big right angle in it.

So just one smooth curved line without the right angle.

It's pretty basic and uses the Raphael elliptical arc.

You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/mailrox/uuAjV/1/

Here's the code:

```
    var raph = Raphael(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

var x = 150;
var y = 150;
var r = 100; //radius
var value = 100;
var maxValue = 360;

var pi = Math.PI;
var cos = Math.cos;
var sin = Math.sin;
var t = (pi/2) * 3; //translate
var rad = (pi*2 * (maxValue-value)) / maxValue + t;

var p = [
  "M", x, y,
  "l", r * cos(t), r * sin(t),
  "A", r, r, 0, +(rad > pi + t), 1, x + r * cos(rad), y + r * sin(rad),
  "z"
];

var param = {"stroke-width": 30}

var d = raph.path(p).attr(param);
```

One way I've done is I could mask the right-angle sections of the lines out however I'd rather not have this and just have once nice curve opposed to managing both that current path and a mask over the top.

Really appreciate some help with this thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Just take the close path (the 'z') off your SVG path definition (note I didn't test this solution):

```
var raph = Raphael(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

var x = 150;
var y = 150;
var r = 100; //radius
var value = 100;
var maxValue = 360;

var pi = Math.PI;
var cos = Math.cos;
var sin = Math.sin;
var t = (pi/2) * 3; //translate
var rad = (pi*2 * (maxValue-value)) / maxValue + t;

var p = [
  "M", x, y,
  "l", r * cos(t), r * sin(t),
  "A", r, r, 0, +(rad > pi + t), 1, x + r * cos(rad), y + r * sin(rad)
];

var param = {"stroke-width": 30}

var d = raph.path(p).attr(param);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzrZU/)

Comment: That works for eliminating the horizontal part of the quasi-right angle. If you don't want the vertical part either, just change the "l" to "m" in the second path command, so that you jump to 12-o'clock instead of drawing a line from the center.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `Raphael` object to include an `arc` function.

The arc calculation has been modfied from Raphael's 'Polar clock' demo: http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TmVHq/

```
Raphael.fn.arc = function(cx, cy, value, total, radius) {
    var alpha = 360 / total * value,
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = cx + radius * Math.cos(a),
        y = cy - radius * Math.sin(a),
        path;

    if (total === value) {
        path = [['M', cx, cy - radius], ['A', radius, radius, 0, 1, 1, (cx - 0.01), cy - radius]];
    } else {
        path = [['M', cx, cy - radius], ['A', radius, radius, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
    }

    return this.path(path);
}

var Paper = new Raphael('canvas', 300, 300);
var arc = Paper.arc(150, 150, 270, 360, 100);
arc.attr('stroke-width', 15);​
```